# Spring Batch job parameters in @Configuration class

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to configure a datasource bean by retrieving the database parameters from Program Arguments, but the problem is that I am receiving the following Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
```

Program Arguments:

```
com.myexample.conf.Config taskletExampleJob DBurl=db:3600/db DBuser=test DBpassword=test
```

Java code:

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    public class Config {

        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public DataSource dataSource1(@Value("#{jobParameters['DBurl']}") String url,
                                      @Value("#{jobParameters['DBuser']}") String user,
                                      @Value("#{jobParameters['DBpassword']}") String password) throws Exception {
            Properties dataSourceProperties = new Properties();
            dataSourceProperties.put("url", url);
            dataSourceProperties.put("username", user);
            dataSourceProperties.put("password", password);
            dataSourceProperties.put("defaultAutoCommit", true);
            return BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(dataSourceProperties);
        }

        @Bean
        public org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope stepScope() {
            final org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope stepScope = new org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope();
            stepScope.setAutoProxy(true);
            stepScope.setOrder(0);
            return stepScope;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Program arguments to be **-DBurl=db:3600/db** this way. prefixed with hyphen '-'

Comment: I figured it out and the solution is to use Spring Boot. In this case we don't even have to use jobParameters, but directly @Value("DBurl")

Comment: please consider camel-casing your parameter names to make the world a better place :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and the solution is to use Spring Boot. In this case we don't even have to use jobParameters, but directly @Value("DBurl")